# Recycler view Onclick to open dialog with data present on card view

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement Onclick on my `RecyclerView`. I tried many ways of doing it, but it ends up crashing my application. I also would like to have a dialog when any of the `cardView` is clicked.

I'm using fireBase as my backend, and I'm quite new to this.

Here's my Adapter class:

```
public class BlogRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public List<BlogPost>blogList;
    public Context context;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

    private static final int SECOND_MILLIS = 1000;
    private static final int MINUTE_MILLIS = 60 * SECOND_MILLIS;
    private static final int HOUR_MILLIS = 60 * MINUTE_MILLIS;
    private static final int DAY_MILLIS = 24 * HOUR_MILLIS;
    String dateString;

    public  BlogRecyclerAdapter(List<BlogPost>blogList){
        this.blogList=blogList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item,parent,false);
        context=parent.getContext();
        firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String descData=blogList.get(position).getDesc();
        holder.setDescText(descData);
        String imageUrl=blogList.get(position).getImage_url();
        holder.setBlogImage(imageUrl);
        final String userId=blogList.get(position).getUser_id();
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    String username=task.getResult().getString("Name");
                    holder.setUserData(username);
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        });

        long miliseconds=blogList.get(position).getTimestamp().getTime();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final long diff = now - miliseconds;
        if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
             dateString= "just now";
        } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
             dateString= "a minute ago";
        } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
             dateString= diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " minutes ago";
        } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
             dateString= "an hour ago";
        } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
             dateString= diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago";
        } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
             dateString= "yesterday";
        } else {
             dateString= diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
        }
        // String dateString= DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy",new Date(miliseconds)).toString();
        holder.setTime(dateString);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blogList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private View mView;
        private TextView descView;
        private ImageView blogImageView;
        private TextView blogDate;
        private TextView blogUserName;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
        }

        public void setUserData(String name){
            blogUserName=mView.findViewById(R.id.blogUserName);
            blogUserName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setDescText(String descText){
            descView=mView.findViewById(R.id.blogDesc);
            descView.setText(descText);
        }

        public void setBlogImage(String downloaduri){
            blogImageView=mView.findViewById(R.id.blogImage);
            Glide.with(context).load(downloaduri).apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(30,3))).into(blogImageView);
        }

        public void setTime(String date){
            blogDate=mView.findViewById(R.id.blogDate);
            blogDate.setText(date);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried many methods of implementing, it but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you mean by "crashes my application"?  Is there an exception? [Edit] your question and include the exception. (While you're editing, please also fix your indentation (make it consistent) and remove the extra empty lines. Your code is hard to read as is.) What  "unsuccessful" methods of implementing did you try and how where they unsuccessful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding onClickListener to RecyclerView is a painful process than ListView. But there is a way to do it.

1. Firstly, add this class to your adapter.

   ```
   public static class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
   private OnItemClickListener mListener;

   public interface OnItemClickListener {
       public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

       public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
   }

   GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

   public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
       mListener = listener;
       mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
               View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
               if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                   mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
               }
           }
       });
   }

   @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
       View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
       if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
           mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   @Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

   @Override
   public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept){}
   }
   ```
2. Secondly, add this listener to your activity/fragment

   ```
   recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new BlogRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), recyclerView ,new BlogRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                   @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                       // Do something here...
                   }

                   @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                   }
               })
       );
   ```